# Enterprise Library 3.1 Logging Formatter Template - Include URL Request

Tags: asp.net, logging, c#-2.0, enterprise-library

We have a custom web app built using Ektron v8.0 which uses EL 3.1 and the format template in the logging config is configured as such:

```
<add
      name="Text Formatter"
      type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging"
      template="Timestamp: {timestamp}
Message: {message}
Category: {category}
Priority: {priority}
EventId: {eventid}
Severity: {severity}
Title:{title}
Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}
)}"
                />
```

Is there a template item for Request URL?  Without the request url with querystring parameters, it's difficult to debug errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no template item specifically for the request URL.  You can add the request URL to the extended properties yourself so that the information is logged:

```
string requestUrl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dictionary.Add("RequestUrl", requestUrl);

Logger.Write("My message", dictionary);
```

Since the formatter is logging all dictionary key/values your RequestUrl will show up in the log.

An alternative approach would be to create your own `IExtraInformationProvider` to populate the specific web information you are interested in.  It's really the same thing except using an Enterprise Library interface.

```
public class WebContextInformationProvider : IExtraInformationProvider
{
    public void PopulateDictionary(IDictionary<string, object> dict)
    {
        dict["RequestUrl"] = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    }
}

Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
WebContextInformationProvider webContext = new WebContextInformationProvider();

webContext.PopulateDictionary(dictionary);

Logger.Write("My message", dictionary);
```

Comment: I've looked at the msdn article on the 3.1 logging and I don't see where the documentation is for the templates.  Any ideas?
I'll accept your answer because I think that's the only viable solution.  Thanks for a nice, clear, concise answer.

Comment: @Dave: I couldn't find formal documentation on the template.  This is the best I could find from [The Definitive Guide to Enterprise Library](http://books.google.ca/books?id=eZXOfFiv6A4C&lpg=PA298&ots=Wx-h_siJnE&pg=PA298#v=onepage&q&f=false).