# Enterprise Library Logging WriteLog Param

Tags: enterprise-library

How can i add some custom params to WriteLog procedure (like userid or uri)?

Answer (score 0):

The approach taken in [Enterprise Library 3.1 Logging Formatter Template - Include URL Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946311/enterprise-library-3-1-logging-formatter-template-include-url-request/4949028#4949028) should allow you to do what you want.